# How to save form data with PHP without using Sessions, Databases or Files

Tags: php, json

I'm learning PHP and my teacher told about an exercise in which I have to create an agenda using a form to take data and change or delete the info.

It looks quite easy when use the obvious but, unfortunately I've been banned from use sessions, databases or files, so, I've been having some issues with saving the data.

The teacher said to use json_encode in an input type hidden in order to get the data, but even if I manage to save the submitted info, it will end up changing to the next info.

The big thing is to save form data using json_encode in a input hidden, but after that I don't know how to preserve it.

By the way, I have all of that in the same file, I have another with some utils functions.

In the PHP file I have some functions I haven't use since, first of all, I want it to add the info without removing the above and then the rest.

<----------------- EDIT ----------------->

Here is the modules.php:

```
function getLocalTime() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Atlantic/Canary');
    return date("d-m-Y H:i:s a");
}

function encodeData($data) {
    return json_encode($data);
}

function getData() {
    if(isset($_POST['hiddenInput'])) {
        return json_decode($_POST['hiddenInput'], true);
}
    return [];
}

function addData(&$data) {
    $date = getLocalTime();
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['name'] = $_POST['regName'];
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['surname'] = $_POST['regSurname'];
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['email'] = $_POST['regEmail'];
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['phone'] = $_POST['regTel'];
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['birthday'] = $_POST['regBirth'];
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['addDate'] = $date;
    $data[$_POST['regNid']]['block'] = false;
}
```

And new form code:

```
<?php            
    if(!isset($_POST['hiddenInput'])) {
        $agenda = [];
    } else {
        $agenda = getData();
        // var_dump($agenda);
        addData($agenda);
    }
    print('<pre>'.print_r($agenda, true).'</pre>');
?>
    <form class="w-50 m-auto p-5" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" >
        <div class="body">
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="text" id="registerNid" name="regNid" class="form-control" placeholder="DNI"/>
                <label for="registerName">DNI</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="text" id="registerName" name="regName" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre"/>
                <label for="registerEmail">Nombre</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="text" id="registerSurname" name="regSurname" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos"/>
                <label for="registerUsername">Apellidos</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="email" id="registerEmail" name="regEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                <label for="registerUsername">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="tel" id="registerTel" name="regTel" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono"/>
                <label for="registerPassword">Teléfono</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                <input type="text" id="registerBirth" name="regBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento"/>
                <label for="registerBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sub-register" value="register">Registrarse</button>
            <?php
                $data = [$_POST["regNid"], $_POST["regName"], $_POST["regSurname"], $_POST["regEmail"], $_POST["regTel"], $_POST["regBirth"]];
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value='<?php echo encodeData($data); ?>'>
            <div class="text-center w-100">
                <p>¿Ya existe? <a class="text-info" href="#!">Actualizar datos</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


<?php            
if(!isset($_POST['hiddenInput'])) {
    $agenda = [];
} else {
    $agenda = getData();
    // var_dump($agenda);
    addData($agenda);
}
print('<pre>'.print_r($agenda, true).'</pre>');
?>
<form class="w-50 m-auto p-5" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" >
    <div class="body">
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="registerNid" name="regNid" class="form-control" placeholder="DNI"/>
            <label for="registerName">DNI</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="registerName" name="regName" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre"/>
            <label for="registerEmail">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="registerSurname" name="regSurname" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos"/>
            <label for="registerUsername">Apellidos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="email" id="registerEmail" name="regEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
            <label for="registerUsername">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="tel" id="registerTel" name="regTel" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono"/>
            <label for="registerPassword">Teléfono</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="registerBirth" name="regBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento"/>
            <label for="registerBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sub-register" value="register">Registrarse</button>
        <?php
            $data = [$_POST["regNid"], $_POST["regName"], $_POST["regSurname"], $_POST["regEmail"], $_POST["regTel"], $_POST["regBirth"]];
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value='<?php echo encodeData($data); ?>'>
        <div class="text-center w-100">
            <p>¿Ya existe? <a class="text-info" href="#!">Actualizar datos</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My main goal is to save the data as this:

```
Array(
  [99999999P] => Array
    (
        [name] => Daniel
        [surname] => García
        [email] => daniel@example.com
        [phone] => 678678678
        [birthday] => 1980/02/28
        [addDate] => 11-11-2022 12:16:49 pm
        [blocked] => 
    )
)
```

But I want to save ALL the data I submit in the form, so the Array doesn't reset everytime I submit the info; the final result could be something like this.

```
Array(
  [99999999P] => Array
    (
        [name] => Daniel
        [surname] => García
        [email] => daniel@example.com
        [phone] => 678678678
        [birthday] => 1980/02/28
        [addDate] => 11-11-2022 12:16:49 pm
        [blocked] => 
    )
  [77777777L] => Array
    (
        [name] => Lucia
        [surname] => Santana
        [email] => lucia@example.com
        [phone] => 99999999
        [birthday] => 1990/06/20
        [addDate] => 11-11-2022 12:18:35 pm
        [blocked] => 
    )
)
```

But I'm getting this:
[image]

And it only is saving two user info, when I try to store the third it remove the first.

Comment: _I've been banned from use sessions, databases or files_ The only solution I can think of is to use `localStorage`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, but I can't use localStorage, the thing is till now teacher only has showed us the basic, and we only can use json_decode in order to save the data from the hidden input. It's a pain in the ass, but he showed us it could be done with just that, but he doesn't know how to explain that to us, so, in the end I'm pretty lost.

Comment: You can use `json_encode` but next time you load the page the data must be came from one of forbitten method.

Comment: Sounds like the idea is to preserve state between requests by storing the data in a JSON string, and writing it into a hidden field in a form so that when the form (containing the hidden field) is submitted again the server-side php code will receive back the stored data and can use it. You probably wouldn't do something like that very often in real life but I suppose it's a learning exercise about working in an otherwise stateless environment such as a web application.  (Of course to preserve it again, you must write the updated data into a hidden form field again for the next time.)

Comment: _"The big thing is to save form data using json_encode in a input hidden, but after that I don't know how to preserve it."_ - that already _is_ "preserving" it - as long as you keep submitting this kind of form, it will always be available on the next page then. Of course this only works as long as the user does not leave the site, but if you are not allowed to use any _actual_ more permanent storage mechanisms, that's about the best you will get.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, that's, in a nutshell, what we have to do; it isn't a good practice, but teacher wants us to do it, so I've been fighting with this for a week so far, and it's a real pain in the ass.

Comment: OK. So what exactly is the problem you're having then?

Comment: @ADyson I've added an edit section with the new code and the thing I want to get, but, basically, I want to save ALL the data in an array as I showed in the edit section, but it only is storing two new info, with the third the first one is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This area of your code is causing issues:

```php
<?php
    $data = [$_POST["regNid"], $_POST["regName"], $_POST["regSurname"], $_POST["regEmail"], $_POST["regTel"], $_POST["regBirth"]];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value='<?php echo encodeData($data); ?>'>
```

If I replace it with the following code it works:

```php
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value='<?php echo encodeData($agenda); ?>'>
```

### Explanation

The line:

```php
$data = [$_POST["regNid"], $_POST["regName"], ....
```

Is not organising the array in the form that you want, and unnecessary. The `$agenda` variable already has the correct data at this point, so just using that for the `hiddenInput` field seems appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've struggling with this thing for hours. Really, thanks a lot.